# Regex-like construction to match %([text]) where [text] can contain escaped parens

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to resolve tokens in a string.

What I would like is given input like this:

```
string input = "asdf %(text) %(123) %(a\)a) asdf";
```

That I could run that through regex.Replace() and have it replace on "%(text)", "%(123)" and "%(a\)a)".

That is, that it would match everything between a starting "%(" and a closing ")" *unless* the closing ")" was escaped. (But of course, then you could escape the slash with another slash, which would prevent it from escaping the end paren...)

I'm pretty sure standard regular expressions can't do this, but I'm wondering if any of the various fancy expanded capabilities of the C# regular expression library could, rather than just iterating across the string totally manually? Or some other method that could do this? I feel like it's a common enough program that there has to be *some* way to solve it without implementing the solution from scratch, given the immensity of the .net framework? If I do have to implement iterating through the string and replacing with string.Replace(), I will, but it just seems so inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var regex = new Regex(@"%\(.*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\)");
var result = regex.Replace(source,"");
```

- `%\(` match literal `%(`
- `.*?` match anything non-greedy
- `(?<!\\)` preceding character to next match must not be `\`
- `(?:\\\\)*` match zero or more literal `\\` (i.e. match escaped `\`
- `\)` match literal `)`

Comment: Yep, that "preceding character to next match" was exactly what I suspected might exist but couldn't find. That's a pretty ugly regex, but still nicer than doing it by hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
    String something = "\"asdf %(text) %(123) %(a\\)a) asdf\";";
    String change = something.replaceAll("%\\(.*\\)", "");
    System.out.println(change);
```

The output

```
"asdf  asdf";
```

Comment: That's because your regex is greedy, and your replacement is empty. Try replacing it with something other than the empty string, and you'll see that it's not quite what I asked for: it's matching the whole substring "%(text) %(123) %(a\\)a)", rather than each piece individually. (In actuality I want to capture the text inside each %() and run the group through the Replace overload that takes a MatchEvaluator, but that should be the easy part.) In your simple example, if you told it to replace each match with "!", I would expect to see "asdf ! ! ! asdf", not "asdf ! asdf".